# Function Decomposition - Bound a Rearrangment of the Composition

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-methods

Say I have a function $f(x)$ and its decomposition, which consist of alternatively applying $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ a number of times, i.e.

$$f(x) = (f_2 \circ f_1 \circ \ldots \circ f_2\circ f_1)(x)$$

Now construct a new function, where we have *rearranged* the components

$$\tilde{f}(x) = (f_2 \circ \ldots \circ f_2\circ f_1 \circ \ldots \circ f_1)(x)$$

Is it now possible to bound the norm $\|f(x)-\tilde{f}(x)\|$ between the two functions? If so, what are the possible requirements on $f(x)$. As I am working in the context of differential equations, linear growth and Lipschitz continuity are the standard assumptions, though You are allowed to assume more.